# mediaelement.js Prevent player control from showing on page load

Tags: mediaelement.js

We are trying to figure out how to prevent the player control from showing when the page is originally loaded. We found the code which makes it disappear after you move the mouse and stop for 2.5 seconds but I'm not sure how to prevent it from showing up on load. We want it to be available when the user hovers over, just not on initial load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After declaring your video object:

```
// declare object for video
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1', {
    startLanguage:'en'
});
```

Then use the hideControls method:

```
player.hideControls();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an undocumented option that seems to work with the latest mediaelement.js version. It deactivates the control bar and only shows the play button:

```
<script>
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
    hideVideoControlsOnLoad: true
});
</script>
```